# CakePHP 2.x Project with unknown folder structure and database file, using EnvSwitcher Class

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a new project that is using a plugin class called EnvSwitcher. I went to set up the database file and the database.php file is empty, except for two lines I have never seen:

```
App::uses('EnvSwitcher', 'Lib/EnvSwitcher');
EnvSwitcher::includeBaseFile(__FILE__);
```

The project does not load, only gets white screen. I tried adding the database connect info to the file, and nothing. Tried to even replace the two lines with regular database info, and still nothing. What is going on with this?

Comment: You might want to contact the creator of the plugin as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Environment switching class. You are using the class here:
https://github.com/angelxmoreno/CakePHP-Environment-Switcher/blob/master/EnvSwitcher.php

Check in folder: `Config/env/_default/`

There should be copies of your config files there to modify.

If there is more than folder in: `Config/envs`, then there should be a copy of the files in each one to switch between environments.